# How to force new user or who just register have to fill the form first (FirebaseUI in IOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseUI as registration system, and now user can login by 2 way (facebook and phone number) but now problem is i want new user or first time login must fill the form before go to MainViewController. on the other hand, old user who ever fill the form will go to MainViewController without force to fill the form again.
Now I'm using Xcode 10.2 and FirebaseUI 6.2.1

Now I'm using Xcode 10.2 and FirebaseUI 6.2.1

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class UserLoginViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            //Old user go to segue withIdentifier "GoMain"
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoMain", sender: nil)
            //First time login go to segue withIdentifier "FillForm"

        }

        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()

        guard authUI != nil else {
            return
        }
        authUI?.delegate = self

        let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
            FUIFacebookAuth(),
            FUIPhoneAuth(authUI:FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()!),
        ]
        authUI?.providers = providers

        let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
        authViewController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}

extension UserLoginViewController {

    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {

        if error != nil {
            return
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you storing details about the user anywhere (e.g. Firestore or Realtime Database)? You will likely need to store a flag per user, tracking if they have completed your on boarding form and retrieve it before deciding which view to show them.

Comment: Thank a lot for answer me, I am storing my about the user in Firestore. But now the problem is that i don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: For that you can refer to the firestore documentation - the section on reading data is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) and there is a quick start guide [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)